# gnuplot auto size pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, gnuplot

I'm currently plotting some diagrams with gnuplot and I would like to export them as pdfs. My results are not statisfactory, since I can only plot the canvas' Standard size of 640x480 pixels. How can I change the size of my diagrams automatically? It needs to be automatically, because there size depends on the data. I'm using pdfcairo as terminal now.

Comment: You can change the size of the created pdf in the `set term pdfcairo` command; see `help pdfcairo`. The default size 5x3 inches.

Comment: But while opening the final pdf with Adobe Reader, an error occurs because of a false ratio between the xsize and the ysize

Comment: That seems very strange. Can you a different pdf viewer? Can you post one the pdf files that give you this error and the gnuplot code that you used to generate it? When version/platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 3. Other readers are not possible since Adobe Reader is the enterprise's standard. Although Sumatra pdf Shows the pdf. System: Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: When you execute `set term pdfcairo size 7in,3in; set output 'test.pdf'; plot sin(x); set output` in a fresh gnuplot session, can Adobe Reader open the creating file `test.pdf`? If so, what does it say the page size is?

Comment: I got the error. The size option needs a quantity, e.g. in or cm. In my tutorial, it wasn't mentioned

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, inches are the default unit. Does `set term pdfcairo size 7,3; set output 'test.pdf'; plot sin(x); set output` create a pdf file that Adobe Reader cannot open?

Comment: Yes, your Solutions works perfectly fine. I just assumed that the Standard size is px, and 640x480 Inch is a bit too much for Adobe Reader. Thanks